# How can I get Cell values of grid view?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform application and after load a data on the gridview, I like to edit some of the cells and click a button. Once button click I like to see the changes on the RichTextBox. How can I do that. Is it possible?

Comment: Please, show your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the 2nd part of your question, but you can read the cellvalue of a gridview with

```
GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[cellIndex].Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [DataGridView.CellValueChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The [DataGridViewCellEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will give you row and column index that has been updated.